# How can i use Alize System for Speaker Recognition on Android

Tags: gmm

I have successfully installed Alize in Android studio, However I'm unaware on generating the gmm/world.gmm file. Also, I'm unsure, whether we can use voice recordings in .3gp format. Can anyone guide me, A code snippet would be helpful.

Before the question gets flagged. Please note
1] I have read all the supporting documents on Alize
2] I have gone through all the questions & issues on StackOverflow, GitHub, ResearchGate
3] I tried my luck with TensorFlow and Microsoft Cognitive API, but nothing of which really helped me.

Comment: Try writing a code yourself, test it and then come back here with your code and problems with it. That's probably why you get flagged not because the flagger is a TensorFlow or Cognitive fan.

Comment: @pointerless I wrote the code & I tried really hard. Its just that I want to know how to proceed and tackle the problem

Comment: Then post the code. You may require more than one question to resolve each issue but post code and ask for help with it, that is the point of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this project 
https://github.com/umbatoul/Android-Voice-IDentification-App-using-SPRO-ALIZE-LIARAL/tree/master/assets
You can find a sample world.gmm here. Most probably it will work.

Secondly, if you are following the tutorial at github, you have a few things to do.
SPRO library has some bugs so you need to modify the source. (what you need to do is already answered here; https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/android-alize/issues )

You have to use raw data of your audio file. So it means you cant use 3gp as input. (Just find a basic wav recorder class from internet and remove all header parts. )

Answer (score 0):

For world.gmm file, you should download and run the 01-GMM-UBM tutorial from here http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/ . For running the tutorial you would need binaries of LIA_RAL the source code of which you can get here https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/LIA_RAL . After successfully running the tutorial, you should have a world.gmm file.

As for the recordings, I have used .wav files.

If by this time, you have yourself successfully run android alize, could you kindly let me know whether the results you had were accurate or not ? I have not yet gotten accurate results.